# Does the negative enhance the sentence?

Tags: negation, syntactic-analysis, semantics

When saying, for example, "Isn't that your mother?" versus "Is that your mother?" Is the former  sentence more effective because of the negative?

Comment: You might find this useful to read: http://www.cambridge.org/other_files/downloads/esl/tge/TGE-Chapter4.pdf Go to the page labeled "62" and the section on Positive and Negative Yes/No Questions. This supports @MattGutting's answer.

Comment: *marks down @JLG reference for future ... reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"More effective", perhaps not. "Is that your mother?" is a more neutrally phrased question, in which the speaker doesn't imply any expectations of how the sentence will be answered; "Isn't that your mother?" (like all "Isn't that X?" questions) typically expects a "Yes" answer.